# Why do I need to Dispose a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage instance?

Tags: c#, email

What unmanaged resources does it allocates that needs to be disposed? Isn't it just a simple array of  managed data? So why disposing?

Comment: Because it implements IDisposable :)

Comment: @csharptest.net That is not a reason.

Comment: @Ci3 It is! If something implements IDisposable, its API is asking for disposal. If you don't dispose, something bad might happen. Exceptions might exist, but they're exceptions.

Comment: @Raphael I understand why you should dispose objects if they implement that class, but the comment is just an implementation detail. It doesn't explain what the un-managed data in that class is.

Comment: @Ci3 Agreed! But since its just a comment, then I guess it's OK (I would not accept it if it was an answer :) ).

Comment: @Raphael Agreed :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A mail message has attachments -> attachments are Streams -> Streams are to be disposed.

Here is the decompiled Dispose method of MailMessage:

```
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && !this.disposed)
        {
            this.disposed = true;
            if (this.views != null)
            {
                this.views.Dispose();
            }
            if (this.attachments != null)
            {
                this.attachments.Dispose();
            }
            if (this.bodyView != null)
            {
                this.bodyView.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

As a general rule a class should implement IDisposable if any of its contained children implement it.

Comment: So does that means that if a message don't have any attachments it doesn't need to be disposed?

Comment: @Raphael If something implements IDisposable, you should dispose it. Also you can see that it has other things that it disposes too.

Comment: Every rule has its [exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable), but this is not one of the exceptions.

Answer (score 14):

A MailMessage can have attachments, an attachment is represented by MIME part which itself holds a Stream. This Stream needs closing as it might hold an unmanaged pointer to the underlying data.