# Sending multiple emails containing the same attachment

Tags: c#, email

I want to send multiple emails containing the same pdf document using a for loop, 
now the first email address always recieves the email but then an error occurs for the follwing email addresses `The process cannot access the file 'file\path\file.pdf' because it is being used by another process.

```
 foreach (GridViewRow Row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                           MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
                            mail.From = new MailAddress(Sender);
                            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
                            mail.Subject = Subject;
                            mail.Body = TextBox2.Text;

                            Attachment attachment;
                            attachment = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/temp/file.pdf"));
                            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                            SmtpServer.Port = SmtpPort;
                            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Sender, Password);
                            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                            try
                            {
                                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                                sent++;
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Label1.Visible = true;
                                Label1.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
                                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                                {
                                    Label1.Text = ex.InnerException.ToString();
                                    Label1.Visible = true;
                                }
                            }
                            Label2.Text = "Sent: " + sent + "Failed: " + failed + " Without Email:" + NoEmail;
                            Label2.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Post relevant code please.

Comment: Sounds like you're either not disposing of the file or not disposing the MailAttachment from the first email

Comment: just added the code

Answer (score 3):

You need to dispose your `MailMessage` (which will dispose the attchments too).

**Easy fix**

```
using (var mail = new MailMessage()) {
 //yourcode
}
```

You may take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477769/why-do-i-need-to-dispose-a-system-net-mail-mailmessage-instance)

**Other solution**

Another way could be to just create your mailmessage before the loop, add the new `To` addresses in the loop, and send it after the loop.

Depends if you wanna send one or many messages.

Comment: thanks guys but the fix is not helping me, am now a receiving a `System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.` error but the first one still sends